# How to fit img like cover background in div?

Tags: html, css, sass

What I mean by that is that say I have the following html:

```
<div class="section-cover__image-container">
  <img class="section-cover__image" src="{{ image }}" />
</div>
```

How would I style the container and image so that the image acts asif it is being used as a background image on the div using `background-size: cover`, with `no-repeat` and `center`?

Comment: Is scaling required? Just setting the wrapper to `inline-block` would work. Otherwise, perhaps `object-fit`?

Comment: Exactly same behaviour is not possible without javascript. If width > height you will set a `max-width` property on the image and the other way around. https://jsfiddle.net/4jajjrk8/1/.